# Coffee Roasting Yields

Tags: roasting

I am trying to understand yield control in coffee roasting. In other areas of the food industry I work in, controlling yield is crucial to commercial success eg input less moisture loss + finished product measured as a percentage.
Are recovery percentages accepted as standards regardless of the fluctuation in moisture in green beans? How do roasters with an eye to quality, flavour and commercial performance optimize their yields?
Thanks